# cannot use protected member of parent class in std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11

I have class `A` and `B`:

```
class A
{
protected:
    void someFunc() {};
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B()
    {
         auto a = std::bind(&A::someFunc, this);
    }
};
```

Why I cannot use `bind` for protected method `someFunc`? It should be accessible as I `bind` it with `this`.

Comment: Use `&B::someFunc` instead of `&A::someFunc`.

Comment: I have read the question marked as duplicate, but could not understand. Actually @Nawaz helped me. Used `B::someFunc` and it worked nice.

Comment: @Nawaz please write and answer and I will accept it. In that way the others who will look for the solution of this problem will easily find it as not all comments are being red usually.

Comment: Once a question is marked as duplicate, it is closed and you can no longer post an answer.